# "Set Value" in Filemaker adding records

Tags: filemaker

I'm working with a Filemaker script (I'm very inexperienced with Filemaker) and I'm trying to use a double nested loop to accomplish an update on all the portal rows for each record.  I'm trying to basically append an 'x' to each portal row's "Desc" field.

[image]

It's working except that the inner loop isn't exiting and it just keeps inserting rows into the portal table with 'x' values.  When I threw in an early exit I can see the outer loop is working fine.  Is "Set Field" supposed to be creating new rows?  How can I get this to exit before that happens?  I'm aware that I can use "Replace Field Contents" but I'm just teaching myself Filemaker scripting and would like to know why this isn't working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck the option 'Allow creation of records in this table via this relationship' under the details of the relationship on your relationship graph.

With this option checked, any portal created using that relationship has a blank line at the bottom allowing new records to be added. Your 'Set Field' script step is setting that field in the new record line in the portal and therefore creating new records.

Uncheck the option and that blank line disappears and the script will exit.

Your other option, if you want to leave that blank line there, is to amend your script so that it actually works on the related records in their associated table rather than directly on the portal.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm assuming the first solution would disallow the user to add new records?  How would I go about the 2nd way?  Is there a command like "select all records from table x"?

Comment: Yes, unchecking that option will stop users from adding new records simply by writing into the portal. You could however script the adding of new records, which is good practice in general as it allows you to validate the contents of the entry etc. Alternatively, use the 'Go to Related Records' script step to go to a layout showing the records from the portal in their parent table. You can loop through them there without fear of creating new records and then return to where you came from.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the 'Exit Loop If' script step that tests if a specific field within the portal related record IsEmpty.